# UIAlertController does not have a similar didDismissWithButtonIndex command

Tags: ios, uialertview, uialertcontroller

Because of a glitch with iOS 8 where the keyboard does not popup automatically with UIAlertView's, my only alternative is to upgrade to UIAlertController. However, the didDismissWithButtonIndex was flexible enough to do what I had to do whereas their proposed new solution is not (as seen in the example below). Without didDismissWithButtonIndex, I cannot upgrade to UIAlertController. Is there a similar solution other than:

```
  UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:cancelButtonTitle style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    }];

    UIAlertAction *otherAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:otherButtonTitle style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    }];

    [alertController addAction:cancelAction];
    [alertController addAction:otherAction];
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the way you did it is the only way you can. I recommend extracting common behavior between the two actions to a separate method and calling that method from the blocks.

Comment: Are you sure? Without a similar method like that, there is no technical way for me to upgrade to UIAlertController. It is simply not flexible enough. Hopefully they fix the keyboard glitch in 8.0.1 or something because my customers will have to tap on the keyboard every time to input text into it because of that glitch.

Comment: I don't see how `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` can do something that is impossible using the new API. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Sometimes there are processes that run after the display of the alert view. Multi-threading it with alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex: prevents a crash that I am getting using UIAlertController.